# Rails scope query on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model with this relationship:

```
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enrollment_plans
  has_many :enrollments, through: :enrollment_plans
  ...
end
```

**EDIT** Here is the join table:

```
class EnrollmentPlan < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :enrollment, required: true
  belongs_to :plan, required: true
end
```

I tried to throw this scope on the model:

```
scope :for_enrollment, -> (enrollment) { where('enrollments.enrollment_id = ?', enrollment.id) }
```

but I get the following error. I am trying to figure out why I can't do this query. What do I need to change it to?

```
pry(main)> Plan.for_enrollment(Enrollment.last).to_a
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "enrollments"
LINE 1: SELECT "plans".* FROM "plans" WHERE (enrollments.enrollment_...
                                             ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord does not include associations by default, you need to add `enrollments` to query by hand. Try:

```
scope :for_enrollment, -> (enrollment) do
  joins(:enrollments).
  where('enrollments.id = ?', enrollment.id)
end
```

This scope will make query with joins of three tables: plans, enrollment_plans and enrollments. You may do the same logic with two tables query:

```
scope :for_enrollment, -> (enrollment) do
  joins(:enrollment_plans).
  where('enrollment_plans.enrollment_id = ?', enrollment.id)
end
```

Comment: That makes sense. However, I am still getting the error that ` column enrollments.enrollment_id does not exist`

Comment: Right. `enrollments` does not have column `enrollment_id`. I will change the answer

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.